# Computing modular inverses for a sequence of numbers

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I have a prime $p$ and an integer $L$ such that $p \gg L \gg 1$, and I need to compute modular inverses of numbers $1, 2, \ldots, L$ (modulo $p$). Obviously I could apply the extended gcd algorithm to each number in turn, however I was wondering if there is a faster way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The better solution might be to use Euler's formula $a^{\varphi{(n)}} = 1 \bmod{n}$ where $\mbox{gcd}(n,a) = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One useful optimization is to compute multiple inverses at a time e.g. compute $\,d = 1/abc,\,$ then $1/a = bc/abc = bcd.\,$ Similarly, $\,1/b = acd,\,\ 1/c = abd.$  This requires only one inversion, trading off other inversions for simpler multiplications.

E.g. to invert $\,9,10,11$ mod $101$ we invert $\,9(10)11 \equiv 9(9) \equiv -20\!:\,\ {-}1/20 \equiv 100/20\equiv \color{#c00}5,\,$ so
$$\begin{eqnarray} &&1/9\ \equiv 10(11)\color{#c00}5\equiv\quad\  9(5)\equiv\ \ \  45\\   
 &&1/10\equiv \,9(11)\color{#c00}5\equiv\ \  {-}2(5)\equiv -10\\  
&&1/11\equiv\, 9(10)\color{#c00}5\equiv {-}11(5)\equiv -55\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you only need to do it for primes up to $L$.  Then you can use things like $\frac 16=\frac 12 \cdot \frac 13$

Comment: Thanks! -- I think this could be turned into an Eratosthenes' sieve-like algorithm. I'll have to think more on this.